# self.filter=[[FilterClass alloc] init]; in Swift? self.filter = FilterClass.self?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm converting some Obj-C to Swift and I'm having issues with some initializers. I have put comments where I am unclear about the init methods. Secondly I'm getting a lot of "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Double' with an index of type 'int'" errors in places like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhWkz.png.  Could you help me clean my code please? Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation


let minFramesForFilterToSettle = 10

enum CurrentState {
case statePaused
case stateSampling
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {


let session = AVCaptureSession()
var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
var validFrameCounter: Int = 0
var pulseDetector = PulseDetector.self              // Is this initialized correctly?
var filter = Filter.self                            // Is this initialized correctly?
var currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling       // Is this initialized correctly?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //self.filter = Filter()                        // Do I need this?
    //self.pulseDetector = PulseDetector.self       // Do I need this?
    startCameraCapture() // call to un-used function. TO DO create function
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

let NZEROS = 10
let NPOLES = 10

class Filter {

var xv = [Float](count: NZEROS + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
var yv = [Float](count: NPOLES + 1, repeatedValue: 0)

func processValue(value: Float) -> Float {

    let gain: Float = 1.894427025e+01

    xv[0] = xv[1]; xv[1] = xv[2]; xv[2] = xv[3]; xv[3] = xv[4]; xv[4] = xv[5]; xv[5] = xv[6]; xv[6] = xv[7]; xv[7] = xv[8]; xv[8] = xv[9]; xv[9] = xv[10]; xv[10] = value / gain;
    yv[0] = yv[1]; yv[1] = yv[2]; yv[2] = yv[3]; yv[3] = yv[4]; yv[4] = yv[5]; yv[5] = yv[6]; yv[6] = yv[7]; yv[7] = yv[8]; yv[8] = yv[9]; yv[9] = yv[10];
    yv[10] =   (xv[10] - xv[0]) + 5 * (xv[2] - xv[8]) + 10 * (xv[6] - xv[4])
    + ( -0.0000000000 * yv[0]) + (  0.0357796363 * yv[1])
    + ( -0.1476158522 * yv[2]) + (  0.3992561394 * yv[3])
    + ( -1.1743136181 * yv[4]) + (  2.4692165842 * yv[5])
    + ( -3.3820859632 * yv[6]) + (  3.9628972812 * yv[7])
    + ( -4.3832594900 * yv[8]) + (  3.2101976096 * yv[9]);
    return yv[10];
}

}

let maxPeriod = 1.5
let minPeriod = 0.1
let invalidEntry = -11
let maxPeriodsToStore = 20
let averageSize = 20



class PulseDetector {

var upVals: Float?
var downVals: Float?
var upValIndex: Int?
var downValIndex: Int?
var lastVal: Float?
var periodStart: Float?
var periods: Double?
var periodTimes: Double?
var periodIndex: Int?
var started: Bool?
var freq: Float?
var average: Float?
var wasDown: Bool?


func reset() {


    for var i=0; i < maxPeriodsToStore; i++ {
        periods[i] = invalidEntry // obviously not Swift so how can I fit it?
    }
    for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {
        upVals[i] = invalidEntry    // same here
        downVals[i] = invalidEntry  // same here 
    }
    freq = 0.5
    periodIndex = 0
    downValIndex = 0
    upValIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: What are you even asking....?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/2792531

Comment: Did you read the question?  It says, `self.filter=[[FilterClass alloc] init];` in Swift? `self.filter = FilterClass.self`?   Thanks for the down vote. It's English.  Key words "in Swift?"

Comment: Yes.  I read every word and bit of code you wrote.  What are you trying to do, in plain English?  [Please read this meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/2792531).

Comment: This also isn't a C function.

Comment: I'm sure it is Edward.  Are you asking for a review of your Objective-C code?

Comment: I'd like to know what `self.filter=[[FilterClass alloc] init];` is in Swift. I tried `self.filter = FilterClass.self` and there were no errors but using 2 references to self seems odd.

Comment: `self.filter = [[FilterClass alloc] init];` is nothing but syntax errors in Swift.  If you want to ask about how to do something (for example, instantiating an object) in Swift, ask it in plain English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how you would convert

```
self.filter=[[FilterClass alloc] init];
```

to Swift, the below line of code would be the answer

```
self.filter= FilterClass()
```

Comment: From the information you have provided, I assume that you might have either initialized `filter` property to  `FilterClass.self` or defined it like this: `var filter: FilterClass.Type`. This makes the type of the property `FilterClass.Type`.  `FilterClass.self` is equivalent to `[FilterClass class]` in Objective C.

Comment: So if you want the `filter` property to be of type `FilterClass`, define the property as  `var filter: FilterClass`

Comment: `var pulseDetector = PulseDetector.self `   and                                                           
`var filter = Filter.self    `  these lines of code are incorrect because they are initializing the properties pulseDetector and filter to the meta types of classes Filter and PulseDetector respectively.

Comment: You can declare them as : `var pulseDetector: PulseDetector` and `var filter: Filter` and initialize them in viewDidLoad as : 'self.pulseDetector =  PulseDetector()` and `self.filter = Filter()`

Comment: Or you can initialize the properties as part of declaration: `var filter = Filter()` and `var pulseDetector = PulseDetector()` .. hope this helps.

Comment: OMG Thank you soooooooooo much!!!!!!  I am studying Obj-C and Swift at the same time and sometimes it's driving me crazy. You gave me more help than anyone else. You are very patient man! Thank you!!    I will be posting many more questions with my remaining code.  Is it possible to follow me on StackFlow?  I will click correct answer every time :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: How can I get your attention with other questions? Do you teach? I am looking for an email tutor I can pay via Paypal.  If you're interested please email me. kansaihappy (AT) gmail.

Comment: @muneeb-rahim Please take a look :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762242/problems-with-some-for-loops-cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-double-with